# Character varying error on heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having an issue deploying to heroku, however my app works fine locally. I'm getting:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...category_id" = 1 AND "questions"."start_language" = 1 AND "q...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add     explicit type casts.
: SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions"  WHERE "questions"."category_id" = 1 AND "questions"."start_language" = 1 AND "questions"."end_language" = 2
```

It's weird because my category_id, which it is saying is not an integer, is stored as an integer in the database:

```
  Column     |            Type             |                       Modifiers
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('questions_id_seq'::regclass)
 category_id    | integer                     | 
 query          | character varying(255)      |
```

**I have fixed my problem and my app has been deployed to Heroku successfully. Things I had to change:**

1. my database was sqlite3 and not postgres
2. the problem was not with the category_id, but with the start and end language data type, sqlite3 was being very forgiving and rendering the languages from their id's. postgres not so much.
3. reseed my database with the right information

Overall it was because there were a lot of smaller errors that were coming together and blowing up the app after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you migrate your production database:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```